# What's causing my header to move about?

Tags: css, header, css-float, clearfix

I'm working on a simple layout that requires a header, footer and main content in between. However, something is bugging me a little. If I include an image beneath my header http://www.reversl.net/before/ everything sits exactly where I want. But if I remove the image my header gives itself a margin from the top of the page as shown here http://www.reversl.net/after/ I'm guessing it's related to my floated header and it's floated contents not being cleared. But I've included the clearfix hack and that doesn't seem to have changed things. Any ideas?

```
<body>
<div class="header clearfix">
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="wrap-inner">
        <ul id="nav-dash">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="header-avatar" src="http://placehold.it/15x15" width="15px" height="15px" alt="" /> YOU &#9660;</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="first"><a href="#">one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul><!--.nav-->
        <div id="logo"><a href="#">LOGO</a></div><!--#logo-->
    </div><!--.wrap-inner-->
</div><!--#wrap-->
</div><!--#header-->
```

```
<div class="wrap-inner">
    <h1>Main Content Here...</h1>
</div><!--.wrap-inner-->
```

```
<footer>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="wrap-inner">
        <p>Footer Text Here....</p>
    </div><!--.wrap-inner-->
</div><!--#wrap-->
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, why do you use multiple items with id='wrap'?

I added

```
{
clear:both;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

to your main content container(it's also a 'wrap'), and it seems to work.

Comment: Awesome! This works. The reason I have multiple wraps with the same styling is because I'm working on a fluid layout whereby the outer wrap is 1280px some content like the header image will fill the browser screen but most of the main content will sit within a 960px wrap that I've called .wrap-inner. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You used clear:both in your solution. I added a clearfix to the parent div of the floated items (the header) should that not have done the same thing as adding clear:both to the main content?

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't use multiple elements with the same id, id is supposed to be unique http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp
It's best to use class instead.

Comment: you didn't define any styling for the class "clearfix"! It's not a magic class that automatically fixes stuff :P You can find some code examples on the web and add it to your css.

Comment: Your right, I should be using a class. Rookie mistake! Regarding the clearfix, I actually did define styling for the class. In my original file I use html5 boilerplate which has clearfix styling included. I reduced the markup/styling in my links above to help people find what might be causing the problem related to my header. In the muddle I forgot to include the clearfix styling :-() Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the H1 margin in main content.

```
.wrap-inner h1 {margin-top:0}
```

Comment: Cheers Jumancy @luke2012 while this does fix the mysterious header margin it means I can't add any margin to my H1 tag beyond {margin-top:0}?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't set any base styles. For example:

```
H1 {
     font-size:2em;
     margin-top:1em;
     ......
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
body
    {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```